# Why nuxtServerInit req session Repeated receiving and not receiving data?

Tags: express, session, vuex, nuxt.js, nuxtserverinit

My Project is Nuxt.js

Here is My Github > https://github.com/zoz0312/Nuxt_Blog

Question. my nuxt store action, nuxtServerInit req Repeated receiving and not receiving data

Help me


This is scenario

1. Server Start
2. Login and make session
3. refresh nuxt web location '/'
4. repeat no.3

Before Insert Session Data & log

Insert Data

```
req.session.permission = 'admin';
```

Console.log

```
req.session FRONT Session {
cookie:
{ path: '/',
   _expires: null,
   originalMaxAge: null,
   httpOnly: true },
  __lastAccess: 1572847191781,
  permission: 'admin',
  user_id: 'admin',
  user_pw: 'test' 
}
```

store/index.js

```
nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    console.log('req.session FRONT', req.session);
    if (req.session && req.session.permission) {
        console.log('SET_USER permission', req.session.permission);
        commit('SET_USER', req.session.permission);
    }
}
```

Reapeat refresh page location '/'

```
req.session FRONT Session {
cookie:
 { path: '/',
   _expires: null,
   originalMaxAge: null,
   httpOnly: true },
   __lastAccess: 1572847348860 }
====================================
req.session FRONT Session {
cookie:
 { path: '/',
   _expires: null,
   originalMaxAge: null,
   httpOnly: true },
   __lastAccess: 1572847352944,
   permission: 'admin',
   user_id: 'admin',
   user_pw: 'test' }
```

Repeated Success and Fail every refresh
**Why did it, and how can i fix them??**

Answer (score 0):

Cause, Express-session Option

I change 'saveUninitialized' option

```
saveUninitialized: true > false
```

then clear this problem